# java script for loop program, stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

Hi so ive never done JS before and im struggling to figure out what code should go in the '??????????' space. If some one could help me it would be much appreciated.  (also struggling with opening the file on the command line. I have nodejs installed and ive tried .load 'filename.js' but it dosent recognise .load)

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    fleet[i] = new Taxi(i);
}

for(var i=0; i<fleet.length; i++){
    print("Taxi with badge number " + fleet[i].badgeNumber + " is " + fleet[i].color);
}

??????????????? = "White";

for(var i=0; i<fleet.length; i++){
    print("Taxi with badge number " + fleet[i].badgeNumber + " is " + fleet[i].color);
    fleet[i].blowHorn()
}
```

this is the desired output:

```
>>> load("assignment.js")
Taxi    with    badge   number  0   is  yellow
Taxi    with    badge   number  1   is  yellow
Taxi    with    badge   number  2   is  yellow
Taxi    with    badge   number  3   is  yellow
Taxi    with    badge   number  4   is  yellow
Taxi    with    badge   number  0   is  White
Beep!
Taxi    with    badge   number  1   is  White
Beep!
Taxi    with    badge   number  2   is  White
Beep!
Taxi    with    badge   number  3   is  White
Beep!
Taxi    with    badge   number  4   is  White
Beep!
```

Comment: The javascript should not be opened inside a command prompt

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: I would suggest some basic JavaScript or Node tutorials are a good place to start.

Comment: Please follow this documentation to learn how to use node.js https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/340/getting-started-with-node-js#t=201611021354306756952

Comment: my task is to load it in the command line so i assume it can be opened, ive been looking at tutorials on W3Schools but ill check this one out now also thankyou

Comment: i apologise for not putting the output. im new to posting on here and i forgot. ive edited it in now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace the below line

```
??????????????? = "White";
```

with

```
fleet.map((itm) => itm.color = "white");
```

Comment: thankyou, how would i open the file in the node.js command line to see if it works?

Comment: if you just wanted to execute just type 'node filename.js'
You can't open the file using node.
you may need to change the directory, where the .js file exists.
then goto node command prompt.
and then use .load filename.js, Otherwise, specify absolute/relative path along with the filename in the .load command. it should work

Comment: sorry your right i meant execute. im getting this error however: ReferenceError: fleet is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lewis\desktop\portfolio.js:2:1)

    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    and then alot more like the last line. 

p.s. thankyou for the help!

Comment: the task also says this: Taxi objects should inherit color, and numWheels, and blowHorn from Vehicle. I take it there is more for me to do, could it be explained?

Comment: You may need to define a function constructor for your Taxi and add all required attributes and methods in your prototype object. With that you would be able to inherit it.